# Do I calculate it right for the hypothesis testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Problem: the lifespan of some items follows the normal distribution N$ (\mu, \sigma^2)   $, with $\mu $ and $\sigma$ both unknown. Now we have $N=16$ of the items whose lifespans have the mean of $\bar{X}=241.5$ (hours) and the variance of $s^2=98.7259$. Is it reasonable to believe that the average lifespan $\mu$ is more than $\mu_0=225$ (hours)?  ($\alpha=0.05, t_{0.05}(16-1)=1.7531$)

My Answer is:

suppose:

$H_0:\mu\le225$

$H_1:\mu>225 $

and we have:  $$t = \frac{\bar{X}-\mu_0}{s/\sqrt{N}} = \frac{241.5-225}{(98.7259)^{0.5}/\sqrt{16}} \approx 6.6424 > t_{0.05}(16-1)=1.7531$$
So, I refuse $H_0$, accept $H_1$, which means that the average lifespan of items $\mu$ is more than $\mu_0=225$ (hours).

Does everybody agree with my answer?

Comment: Looks very reasonable to me.